# modifying an ssd net in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, architecture, tensorflow-ssd

If I were using Keras, Modifying the architecture would be straight forward modification of the network layers:

```
        x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(inputs)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)
        x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
        x = Activation("relu")(x)
        x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)
```

But I cant seem to find that structure in Tensorflow:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.config

Am I looking at the right file? In other words, how would I go about adding extra layers (whether convolutional, maxpool, or fully connected) to my tensorflow model?

Comment: The file linked in the question is only a configuration file used to define various parameters like `kernel_size` and `use_dropout`. You will not find the model architecture right there. Instead go for the TF Object Detection API.

Comment: The TF Object Detection API is what I am working with, I'm just not sure which file contains the neural net architecture

Comment: I was thinking it could be the "models" file:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_feature_extractor.py
But that looks nothing like the architecture featured in 
https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-M8UvZJWNW4E/WsKk-tbzp8I/AAAAAAAAChw/OqxBVPbDygMIQWGug4ZnHNDvuyK5FBMcQCLcBGAs/s1600/image5.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the actual model has been abstracted away to
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet/mobilenet_v2.py

Though I would imagine there has got to be a simpler way to change the architecture of the neural net than just modifying that file...